# is it possible to use only two semaphores to synchronise three or more threads?

Tags: operating-system, posix

We have three threads or more, can we use only two semaphores (binary or counting semaphores)? An idea that popped into my mind is playing with the number of sem_post-s and sem_wait-s. 
Any ideas, strategies are welcomed.

Comment: mouviciel's answer is accurate and probably sufficient - the number of semaphores is really independent of the number of threads.  I single semaphore can synchronize hundreds of threads, but perhaps there's more to your question.  Can you elaborate a bit on what your threads are doing and why they need to be synchronized?

Answer (score 2):

A semaphore is used to protect a shared resource. You need as many semaphores as shared resources, this is not linked to how many threads access these resources.

Comment: if you have concurrency between threads and the race condition occurs, one semaphore is not enough. i.e. there are three threads that run several iterations. If I want those three threads to execute in a particular order, say iteration 0 - threadA, threadB, threadC; iteration 1 - threadA, .... multiple semaphores need to be implemented. 
So far I've found out that there can be two semaphores doing this. however, could it be done with only one?

Comment: Why use threads if they are executed sequentially? answer to this question may reveal some hidden resources that you want to protect.